# How to Build Splunk Search Query for below Scenario

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am able to get the multiple events (api's logs) in splunk dashboard like below

**event-1:**

```
{ "corrId":"12345", "traceId":"srh-1", "apiName":"api1" }
```

**event-2:**

```
{ "corrId":"69863", "traceId":"srh-2", "apiName":"api2" }
```

**event-3:**

```
{ "corrId":"12345", "traceId":"srh-3", "apiName":"api3" }
```

I want to retrieve `corrId` (ex:- "corrId":"12345") dynamically from one event (api log)by providing apiName and build splunk search query based on retrieved `corrId` value that means it will pull all the event logs which contains same `corrId` (`"corrId":"12345"`).

**Output**

In above scenario expected results would be like below

**event-1:**

```
{ "corrId":"12345", "traceId":"srh-1", "apiName":"api1" }
```

**event-3:**

```
{ "corrId":"12345", "traceId":"srh-3", "apiName":"api3" }
```

I am new to splunk, please help me out here, how to fetch `"corrId":"12345"` dynamically by providing other field like `apiName` and build Splunk search query based on that.

I have tried out like below, but to no luck.

```
index = "test_srh source=policy.log [ search index = "test_srh source=policy.log | rex field=_raw "apiName":|s+"(?[^"]+)" | search name="api1" | table corrId]
```

This query gives event-1 log only but we need all other events which contain same `corrId` (`"corrId":"12345"`). Appreciate quick help here.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're explicitly extracting the `apiName` field, I'll assume the `corrId` field is not automatically extracted, either.  That means putting `corrId="12345"` in the base query won't work.  Try `index=test_srh source=policy.log corrId="12345"` to verify that.

If the corrId field needs to be extracted then try this query.

```
index=test_srh source=policy.log 
| rex "corrId\\":\\"(?<corrId>[^\\"]+)"
| where [ search index = "test_srh source=policy.log 
  | rex "apiName\":\"(?<name>[^\"]+)" 
  | search name="api1" 
  | rex "corrId\\":\\"(?<corrId>[^\\"]+)" 
  | fields corrId | format ]
```

Note: I also corrected the regex to properly extract the apiName field.

Comment: Thanks a Lot for your Answer, as per my even logs field name is "x-xxxCorrId" instead of "corrId". i had tried with above query to replace "correId with" "x-xxxCorrId" but i am getting the following syntax error like--  Error in 'rex' command:  Encounter the following error while compiling rex 'x-xxxCorrId\":\"(?<'x-xxxCorrId'>[^\"]+)"  Regex: syntax error in subpattern name (missing terminator).. i have tried out many ways still not resolved

Comment: The embedded quotation marks need additional escaping.  I've modified the answer.

Comment: this time got the following error like -- Error in 'SearchParser': Mismatched ']'. Below one is the query I used --   index=test_srh source=policy.log 
| rex "x-xxxCorrId\\":\\"(?<'x-xxxCorrId'>[^\\"]+)"
| where [ search index = "test_srh source=policy.log 
  | rex "apiName\":\"(?<name>[^\"]+)" 
  | search name="api1" 
  | rex "x-xxxCorrId\\":\\"(?<'x-xxxCorrId'>[^\\"]+)" 
  | fields x-xxxCorrId| format ]

Comment: Try adding another escape character for each embedded quotation mark.  Also, try to avoid using hyphens in field names.

Comment: now again getting the first time error--  Error in 'rex' command: Encounter the following error while compiling rex 'x-xxxCorrId\":\"(?<'x-xxxCorrId'>[^\"]+)" Regex: syntax error in sub pattern name (missing terminator). I am not sure why it is appearing

Comment: Why are there single quotes around the field name within `rex`?  That's not valid regex.  Try `rex "x-xxCorrId\\":\\"(?<CorrId>[^\\"])"`.

Comment: it seems copy paste issue in the above comment, have not used single quotes around the field name. still getting the same kind of error. when i tried to remove hypen in field name, getting error like this-- Error in 'where' command: The expression is malformed. An unexpected character is reached at ')'

Comment: Using 3 escape characters works in my sandbox (Splunk 8).  Try this run-anywhere example:

    `| makeresults 
    | eval data="{ \"corrId\":\"12345\", \"traceId\":\"srh-1\", \"apiName\":\"api1\" };
    { \"corrId\":\"69863\", \"traceId\":\"srh-2\", \"apiName\":\"api2\" };
    { \"corrId\":\"12345\", \"traceId\":\"srh-3\", \"apiName\":\"api3\" }" 
    | eval data=split(data,";") 
    | mvexpand data 
    | eval _raw=data 
    | rex "apiName\":\"(?<name>[^\"]+)" 
    | search name="api1" 
    | rex "corrId\\\":\\\"(?<corrId>[^\\\"]+)" 
    | fields corrId 
    | format`

Comment: thanks a lot for your patience, i also following the same way you did but  not sure why it has not been working for me.